# How do you best break the Limit on the number of recursions in typescript tails?

Tags: typescript

The only way I know how to count in typescript is to generate tuples. For example, the following code can convert numbers into tuples, which is a useful trick when doing type gymnastics.

```js
type NumToTuple<T extends number, Arr extends any[] = []> =
    Arr["length"] extends T ?
    (
        Arr
    )
    :
    (
        NumToTuple<T, [...Arr, 1]>
    );
```

However, this code has a disadvantage, it can only support the maximum number of 999, for more than 1000 numbers it can do nothing.

Later, I found a way to break this restriction. The code is as follows

```js
type CountTuple = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336, 337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384, 385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432, 433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456, 457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480, 481, 482, 483, 484, 485, 486, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 509, 510, 511, 512, 513, 514, 515, 516, 517, 518, 519, 520, 521, 522, 523, 524, 525, 526, 527, 528, 529, 530, 531, 532, 533, 534, 535, 536, 537, 538, 539, 540, 541, 542, 543, 544, 545, 546, 547, 548, 549, 550, 551, 552, 553, 554, 555, 556, 557, 558, 559, 560, 561, 562, 563, 564, 565, 566, 567, 568, 569, 570, 571, 572, 573, 574, 575, 576, 577, 578, 579, 580, 581, 582, 583, 584, 585, 586, 587, 588, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 600, 601, 602, 603, 604, 605, 606, 607, 608, 609, 610, 611, 612, 613, 614, 615, 616, 617, 618, 619, 620, 621, 622, 623, 624, 625, 626, 627, 628, 629, 630, 631, 632, 633, 634, 635, 636, 637, 638, 639, 640, 641, 642, 643, 644, 645, 646, 647, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653, 654, 655, 656, 657, 658, 659, 660, 661, 662, 663, 664, 665, 666, 667, 668, 669, 670, 671, 672, 673, 674, 675, 676, 677, 678, 679, 680, 681, 682, 683, 684, 685, 686, 687, 688, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698, 699, 700, 701, 702, 703, 704, 705, 706, 707, 708, 709, 710, 711, 712, 713, 714, 715, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 721, 722, 723, 724, 725, 726, 727, 728, 729, 730, 731, 732, 733, 734, 735, 736, 737, 738, 739, 740, 741, 742, 743, 744, 745, 746, 747, 748, 749, 750, 751, 752, 753, 754, 755, 756, 757, 758, 759, 760, 761, 762, 763, 764, 765, 766, 767, 768, 769, 770, 771, 772, 773, 774, 775, 776, 777, 778, 779, 780, 781, 782, 783, 784, 785, 786, 787, 788, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795, 796, 797, 798, 799, 800, 801, 802, 803, 804, 805, 806, 807, 808, 809, 810, 811, 812, 813, 814, 815, 816, 817, 818, 819, 820, 821, 822, 823, 824, 825, 826, 827, 828, 829, 830, 831, 832, 833, 834, 835, 836, 837, 838, 839, 840, 841, 842, 843, 844, 845, 846, 847, 848, 849, 850, 851, 852, 853, 854, 855, 856, 857, 858, 859, 860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867, 868, 869, 870, 871, 872, 873, 874, 875, 876, 877, 878, 879, 880, 881, 882, 883, 884, 885, 886, 887, 888, 889, 890, 891, 892, 893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908, 909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940, 941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956, 957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972, 973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988, 989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999, 0]

type NumToBigTuple<T extends number, Arr extends any[] = [], Count extends CountTuple[number] = 0> =
    Count extends 999 ?
    (
        NumToBigTuple<T, Arr, 0> & {}
    )
    :
    (
        Arr["length"] extends T ?
        (
            Arr
        )
        :
        (
            NumToBigTuple<T, [...Arr, 1], CountTuple[Count]>
        )
    )
```

This method can support parameters of over 1000, but unfortunately it has serious performance issues, so I believe this method cannot be truly put into use. My question is whether there is a better way to break through the limit of tail recursion times, and the performance should not be too poor?

[Here is a link to the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gVwHbACoLAG2gXigbQEYAaKAJlIGZSAWUgVlIDZSB2UgDlIE5TCAGPiSiEKI6iLojGIliPYiuI3uUHlhZMWQlkpZGWTlkFZJWRWU1lYZTGUJlKZRmU5lBZSWUVNNTWE0YjQSNFI0MjRyNAo0SjQq9Gr0wvRi9BL0UvQy9HL0CvRK9CpMakzCTGJMEkxSTDJMckwKTEpMKqxqrMKsYqwSrFKsMqxyrAqsSqwqHGocwhxiHBIcUhwyHHIcChxKHCrcatzC3GLcEtxS3DLcctwK3ErcKgJqAsICYgISAlICMgI5AIFAIlAIXgIhB9REIfoQ-oQAYQgYQQYQwYQXmQ3mQPpo+NoCX99ASgcYCWDzHxLNSPrZqT9HNSAa5qSDPNSXr4+P4eV9gjy-uEeUDojywfE+IkpR9UlKfpkpQDclKQYUpS9SnxytqvtVtX96tqgc1tWD2nxOpaPr1LT9BpaAaNLSDJpaXrM+PMvV9ll6-usvUDtl6wfs+IcIx9ThGfpcIwDbhGQY8IypsWpsRp+Fp+Dp+Hp+AZ+EZ+CZ+GZ+OnIeoNDD1Dp4aRcQZkc3Ue2zJjm9iexp8eRCYO9CTB0ZyYOzFTyDSZxp6TOdEyZwZWTOTByZ+nueRebutALd3phbujGLd2ZJeRpdeNHLrzpFdeDCrryZ1df01ryDqf1p9T+ehGj+Rimj+ZgWuQVpQRotpQToDpQQYzpQSYbpQemnrkN62FaH62F6IG2FGCG2FmOG5CRpRGgxpROjxpRBhJpRJippRFj8FY-A2DmVB5nxThFnxbhlnxXhVlQNbWDY9bWA4TZQNYLhtopHaqV43aKb2Wk2AOtgOLoVCjrYbgTrYXjTvYVjWFQC72A4y72C4a72B4m72BYO6ODYgRUIejhOCejhuOejheFezhWMkVD3s4DhPs4Livs4Hgfs4Fjfq4NiVFQAGuE4wGuG4YGuF4kHuFY3RUHB7gOIh7guCh7geOh7gWFhng2IsVD4Z4ThEZ4bikZ4XgUd4VjHFQtHeA4DHeC4zHeB4bHeD4nG0NxG1BPxUC+GEQm7SWG0xBWG0+DW-gBPW-ghAp-gRCp-gxOitCaYEfi4rQA6BCEhm7aOgRRBOgRxNOwR+DZu0LsEITLsEERrsEMSbsEPg7qEAS+bth6hGEJ6hFE56hHEV7hH40W7fe4QhE+4QRK+4QxB+4Q+N+kQBDlu0AZEYTAZEURgZEcSQdEfhVbtcHRCEiHRBEKHRDE6HRD4WGxAE3W7fhsRhERsRRKRsRxBR8R+JNu20fEIQMfEETMfEMRsfECTrVAiQpLxrs7YkWQHYkeSiZ7RQSa7NbJCk9bJBkCnJDkKnJAUL0hwk2mpCkA6pBkf2pDkhgMBOqRFNO6RJJD6RpPYDDLukORrukBSbukCQ7pkKRY5kGShAwJ6ZHk56ZEUV7ZEkFPZGk6QME+2Q5K+2QFB+2QJN+uQpJzuQZLUDDAbkeRgbkRSQfkSTi-kaT9AwiH5DkKH5AU6H5AkWGFCkGuFBkqwMERhR5KRhRFBRxRJDNsUNI5wGAMWKDkZixQChsWKCUF2pQKge1KDUAszADqlCaAHUobRg7lDKIQCo9Zyg1AUuUBoKlygtETuUEo2lKgVAHJUGof1KgNFzlASoLRTDMGnNUMokNqhVArpw5c1QGhrmqC0Tc1QSg7lqBULGtQaid04SeWoTRzy1DaFeeoZQKb1CqOPThT56gNFfPUFoH56glG-I0ConNGg1A3pw4CjQmhgUaG0SCzQyji2aFUM+nDELNAaChZoLR0LNBKFhVoFQNatBqO-ThRFWhNFIq0NoFF2hlDNu0KooDOEMXaA0Zi7QWhsXaB0F2nQege06AMNBUBOgjCOs0gOnQpjB26F0QhbB6zdAGApboIwVLdAmInboHRtK9B6AOXoAw-q9BGBw3oEweHNOnP0LokN+h9BEf0IYzg2Brn6BMTc-QOg7kGD0LGgwBiqMGCMSIbBzyDCmFeYYXQKbDD6MY4YQxshsFfMMCYH5hgdG-KMHonNRgDBcaMEYjQ2BgVGFMSC4wuji3GH0IJ4whjDDYChcYEx0LjA6FhSYPQNaTAGMkyYIxNhsFIpMKYFFphdDNtMPohTphDGuGwZi0wJhsWmDMF2swFge1mCsJpswNhtNmDsU6UBZgzBrPMBY9Z5grAUvMDYKl5g7ETvMGY2lFgLAHIsFYf1FgbA4YsHYGzFgzFnMsBYC5lgrGXMsDYa5lg7E3MsGYO5VgLCxqsFYqjVgbBeaq88qw9hXnWHMCm6wljGPWGsIFqrXzrB2B+dYMxvybAWJzTYKwXGbA2Mi1VYFNh7EgtsOY4tthLCCdsNYhLVUoW2DsdC2wZhYV2AsDWuwVjJN2BsJlqrSK7D2BRfYcwzb7CWIU-YawBWquYvsHYbF9gHBdocE4HtDgXCaYcG4bTDgPBVYcA4NZjgnHrMcC4Cljg3BUscB4idjgHG0qcE4A5TgXD+qcG4HDTgPA2acA4s5zgnAXOcC4y5zg3DXOcB4m5zgHB3JcE4WNLgXFUZcG4cbLgPFiDwK81wjgU2uGcYx1wrg5uuHcfIPAPzXAON+W4JxOa3AuC424Nxa23AeK0HgkF7hHHFvcM4QT7hXG7fcO44weDoXuAcLCjwTga0eBcZJjwbgzseA8XYPAKLPCOGbZ4ZxCnPCuFu54dx7g8DYs8FQ-AAC6AAoXzoBIBQAAHIIAALaoDgAAIQAJYAHN0BYAgAAHlQFACAAAPYAEAkAABMADOUAkDhYAEYQAAE6kAAILlfK+lrLOWCtQAAIZIBAPgbzUA8AddIPAZAwB6vZby4VvrKBEvYHwMVsLZXyudbwPwAAfF13zUBVuwEQCgQbjXCueagAAfhW2tgAFIdtba3QsRei-F8bKXUDVdq6QRbUAABkUAADeABfU7UAACU32ABc32TtnbOzV8r+AABE2AkBxeAAACwh51zLQ2mtpYOyD4732MerbB1jtbf3sdQEB4T4HhPzvhci7FhLGBsCpdIPgAAdEzsHfBvO9Y22gGnEB8CjeAN5hbePVsE-x-5gL4BoAXcizd1LW3htFdKxV+7dXkfbZa21jrXWCD8+W6D2rkPoew4R0jhrcu0dA8F1AXHZ3hereJ5jwnku4DS7uwQJnDOWciH599n7ABufzgXoDNcIJrkLFOndc+S4cJ7AB6aPUAAAKzXyvNbCxAbL5XCv5bC81zA2A6vw9ayITi-AoAAGNC9lagPljAYA4Dley7l3zseoAB5a2QTXjuqfS8sJxJbzfE-J9T+nwrcXysQGa+nlvcPC+vBL+XpAUBK-V7ALX+vEBcukBKwgAb8OKuB7H1XirMXECFcgOVgAZnX7PSBS-QBi-l6vEB8ukFa7lqA-XWtxcwDFmHU-79l7gDC1T022zxADL2awQHy2gBAEQDq1L0ALAG3wqygHP0L2ADgBb2awAGtoA4Bz9z8gA)

Comment: As an aside, NumToBigTuple supports a maximum number of 3150

Comment: ① "The only way I know how to count in typescript is to generate tuples."  [There are other ways](https://tsplay.dev/NBBP4N). ② There's a reason they put a tail recursion limit of 1000; performance gets really bad otherwise, as you've seen.  For `NumToBigTuple` you shouldn't need to recurse that deeply to get long tuples; you can do [something like this](https://tsplay.dev/mb3dEW) and get very long tuples with only a few levels deep.  But there are limits on programmatic tuple lengths of ~10K so that's also limited.

Comment: ③ Do you have some important reason for trying to do this type-level math?  What's the actual use case? Is it just for fun or is there something you're trying to support? ⊛ Does this fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz My ultimate goal is to write a basic type tool that can be used daily, for example, to achieve better counting function and generate range numbers. I think this kind of basic tool may be useful. Your answer does provide other ways to accomplish the function I want, and I think it can be used as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually *need* to support [tail-recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) that recurse more than a thousand levels deep, you're probably stuck.  It will either be impossible or you can expect terrible performance.  If the only way to represent some operation in TypeScript's type system is through such types, then it's not the sort of thing TypeScript is currently intended to support.  For example, arbitrary arithmetic operations on numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382) are not currently supported.  If it *were* supported, it would be trivially easy to use, since computers are very good at arithmetic, and you shouldn't get a stack overflow or a performance slowdown calculating something like `12345 * 67890`.

Of course it is possible to use and abuse features of the type system to get close, but this is the sort of thing one does for *fun*, and not necessarily for use in production code.

---

As you mentioned, you can use [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) to perform some arithmetic operations: specifically, you can perform addition and subtraction of non-negative whole numbers of moderate sizes, like below a thousand or ten thousand.  If your use case needs numbers outside or at the edges of those ranges, then you will have a bad time.

Still, there are better and worse ways to use tuples to do this sort of thing.  For example, if the use case is to build a tuple of a specified length, this is discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#26223](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223).  Currently the least intensive technique is to join tuples to themselves, so that the size of the tuple doubles for each level of recursion, instead of merely incrementing the size by one.  This makes it very easy to create very large tuples without getting anywhere near a thousand levels.  For example:

```
type _Big1<N extends number, R extends 0[][] = [[0]]> =
    `${N}` extends keyof R[0] ? R : _Big1<N, [[...R[0], ...R[0]], ...R]>;

type _Big2<N extends number, R, A extends 0[] = []> =
    R extends [infer R0 extends 0[], ...infer RR] ?
    _Big2<N, RR, `${N}` extends keyof [...A, ...R0] ? A : [...A, ...R0]> : A;

type NumToBigTuple<N extends number> = _Big2<N, _Big1<N>>

type C = NumToBigTuple<100>['length']
// type C = 100

type D = NumToBigTuple<500>['length']
// type D = 500

type M = NumToBigTuple<1000>['length']
// type M = 1000

type MMMMM = NumToBigTuple<5000>['length']
// type MMMMM = 5000

type BiggestThisWay = NumToBigTuple<8191>['length']
// type BiggestThisWay = 8191
```

But there's a hardcoded limit in TypeScript that programmatically-generated tuples can be no larger than ten thousand elements, and so this hits a limit too.

Again, this is not meant to say you *should* use this technique for tuples, but it's better than recursing for every element.

---

Another approach people have been taking for performing arbitrary math is to use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) to convert between numeric literals and string literals, and parse the string literals, and perform base-ten arithmetic on the strings.  For example, if you want to add one to a non-negative whole number, you can do it this way:

```
type Succ = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];
type _Inc<T> =
    T extends `${infer F}${Succ[number]}` ? 
      T extends `${F}${infer D extends Succ[number]}`
        ? `${D extends 9 ? _Inc<F> : F}${Succ[D]}` : never : 1;

type Inc<T extends number> = 
  _Inc<`${T}`> extends `${infer N extends number}` ? N : never;

type X = Inc<8675309>
// type X = 8675310

type Y = Inc<12399999>
// type Y = 12400000
```

This is recursive in the base-ten length of the number, so it can easily handle all numeric literals below [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) without getting anywhere close to a thousand levels.

And *again*, this doesn't mean it's a good idea to do this.  It's fun, but if you build software on top of this and it breaks, the TypeScript team will probably not consider it a bug.

---

If ever arithmetic with numeric literal types is truly supported in TypeScript, it will not require such type-juggling.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-Sgx0mKg0HXqADEtBp80XeKlnvwJvZJ-c8mMFzPavUaTuuMuC6ungwN8px-YxseOHkI8sB0O0HOdlB9+oz7wqdenHICAADd6mcFBexiQdh23R8uDXBhXlfYcxmOHRZBPMgxlnLosEwx40noTdwUAggQIYSJRWgAANMFoLQUNGxbZlK24CN-mtflaMzJiWPhHNoAATTot8UDiSsI0kySOITGJhLJOIay1BEASAA)